# "do" loop while entry <> 0

Tags: c++

> Write an application that keeps inputting an integer from the user until zero is entered.
>   The program will calculate and display the average of the numbers, and display the largest and smallest of the numbers.
>   Zero is not to be included in the average, largest or smallest printouts.

I tried it and got this far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string str;
    do {
        cout << "Enter text: ";
        getline (cin,str);
        cout << "You entered: " << str;
        cout <<str + str;
    } while (str != "0");
}
```

How do I get the average of the numbers with only one variable and how do I get the biggest and smallest number?

Comment: Take a look at this brief tutorial on performing basic IO using C++. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to define couple of other variables to track the smallest and largest values. you have to check whether a new number entered by the user is small than the earlier smallest value and whether the new number is larger than the earlier largest value.